# I need one async function to wait for another one

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, es6-promise

I have 2 async functions - one gets ids of towns, and the second one takes these ids and gets {towns} objects. I am importing an API which is also async.

The first function works fine, but the second one returns

> LOG  catchTowns [Error: Not found]

code:

```
import { getTown, getTownIds } from "./api/towns" 

//getting IDs from API

const getTownIdsAsync = async () => {
  const asyncids = await getTownIds()
  return(asyncids.ids)
}

let idcka = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(getTownIdsAsync())
})
.then(result => {
  idcka = result
  for(i=0; i < idcka.length; i++){
  }
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('catchIdcka', err)
})

//getting Towns from API
const getTownsByIdsAsync = async (ajdycka) => {
  const asyncTowns = await getTown(ajdycka)
  return(asyncTowns)
}

let towns = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(getTownsByIdsAsync())
})
.then(result => {
  towns = result
  console.log(towns)
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('catchTowns', err)
})
```

Comment: Please add info about your api calls implementation

Comment: It's all local - there is a file with a collection of towns and events and the getTown and getTownIds are the functions that return the data. getTown returns object, getTownIds returns all the ids of towns.

Comment: But in that case they shouldn't be async

Comment: It's to simulate real world - how it would work if it fetched the data from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you are handling state nor if you are using class or functional components so I'll just give an example how I'd do it using a functional component and hooks.

The `idcka` promise should return something and store its state at some point, maybe just there or using redux. I'll just use the [state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) here.

```js
const [idckaValue, setIdckaValue] = useState([])

// call idcka promise and store result by using the above setter setIdckaValue()...
```

Then, use an [effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to call the second promise when `idckaValue` has changed.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // call towns promise...
}, [idckaValue])
```

This way, we ensure that the `towns` promise only runs when `idckaValue` changes.

And finally here's some [documentation about hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

---

So wrapping up now using an effect hook to the first function too.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
    // The state hook to store idcka value, I'm assuming it's an array here.
    const [idckaValue, setIdckaValue] = useState([]);

    // Your getTownIdsAsync function.
    const getTownIdsAsync = async () => {
        const asyncids = await getTownIds()
        return(asyncids.ids)
    }

    // Your getTownsByIdsAsync function.
    const getTownsByIdsAsync = async (ajdycka) => {
        const asyncTowns = await getTown(ajdycka)
        return(asyncTowns)
    }

    // This hook will only run once because its second argument is an empty array.
    useEffect(() => {
        // Getting IDs from API.

        getTownIdsAsync()
            .then(result => {
                // Let's assume you do something with the data and that the result of it is an array.
                setIdckaValue(result)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('catchIdcka', error)
            })
    }, []);

    // This hook will only run every time idckaValue changes, note its second argument value.
    useEffect(() => {
        // Getting Towns from API

        getTownsByIdsAsync()
            .then(result => {
                // Then you do what you want with result, maybe store it in state and then use it in the render?
                console.log(towns)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('catchTowns', error)
            })
    }, [idckaValue]);

    return (
        // Your render.
    );
}
```

Comment: Using `new Promise` here its useless, async functions already returns a `Promise`

Comment: You are right @ToniBardinaComas, I edited the answer.